# Investigating whether blood relates two Holme women?

Tags: 19th-century, lancashire

I want to investigate whether there is blood related to the two Holme.
They are those who lived in the same age. One side is my distant relatives. (Ann Holme)
The other one is the mother of my great grandfather candidate who I found and found in Japan. If these two people have a blood relationship, I think that the candidate I found would be saying that he is a great grandfather.（Cecil Zohrab Ede)
  [image]

Comment: Hello, AKira. Can you tell us how you know Ann Holme is your distant relative (and what relation she is?) Is she related via the mother of Cecil Zohrab Ede, or have you identified her in some other way?

Comment: Ann Holme is in the family line of a person related to me at Ancestory.com.
Helen Holme is the pre-marital name of mother　of　candidate of my grandfather.
My best grandfather's name is Cecil Zohrab Ede.

Comment: If there is a blood relationship between Helen Holme (Ede) and Ann Holme, I will be related to Helen Holme. Then Helen's son Cecil is supposed to be my great-grandfather. I have been looking for a great grandfather who is British. There are many circumstantial evidences that he is my great-grandfather. But no definitive evidence has been found.

Comment: In Japan, much of the records were burned in the war. Most of the Kobe where the great-grandmother lived was burnt. So there is no record. However, the list of foreigners remains. I looked through all of that list. I looked for a candidate of great grandfather and examined each candidate. There were records of 7 out of 8 people. There was no record for one person. However, the record in England and his office shows my relationship with my great-grandmother.He is Cecil Zohrab Ede.

Comment: I have been invited to everyone here for nearly three years. So I found various circumstantial evidences. I also conducted a DNA test. But no definitive evidence related to C.Z.Ede is found. Both my mother and my aunt are very old and I am hoping to find their grandfather somehow.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English.